# change textarea aws polly in vba to read new text fails

Tags: vba, textarea, amazon-polly

I'm experimenting with AWS Polly in VBA and I'd like to change the default text to be read from "Hi! My name is Salli. I will read any text you type here." to "This is a test message." and then have Salli read it. I can write the code to change the text but Salli always reads the same default text.  The number of characters remaining counter under the textarea box is also not updating.

Here's my code.

```
Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'navigate to aws polly site
    With objIE
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Width = 800
    .Height = 600
    .Visible = True
End With
objIE.navigate ("https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech")
    Do
    DoEvents
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = Nothing
        GoTo the_start:
    End If

Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4

Dim polly As HTMLDocument
Dim narrative As HTMLLIElement
Dim btnReadText As HTMLButtonElement
Set polly = objIE.document
Set narrative = polly.getElementById("awsui-textarea-0")
Set btnReadText = polly.getElementsByClassName("parrot-player-button full-width-button awsui-button awsui-button-size-normal awsui-button-variant-primary awsui-hover-child-icons")(0)
narrative.Focus
narrative.innerHTML = "This is a new test message."
MsgBox narrative.innerHTML
btnReadText.Click
```

This snippet executes without errors but Salli always says the same thing.

Comment: Maybe try `narrative.innerText`.  Kind of difficult to make suggestions without a URL or the relevant page source.

Comment: OK, I added the navigation stuff.

Comment: You need an account to access that page...

Comment: Yes, you do but it's free unless you send it a lot of text.

Comment: I got as far as the request for my credit card info, so you must be looking at a different place. "One month free" is not "free"

Comment: there's a great service called privacy dot com that let's you issue a debit card with a $ limit and time limit. iI use them for sites like this and give it a $1 limit and one-use term.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer elsewhere on the net . The problem is that the input changed event is not being fired. To do this, first set the focus on the textarea and after changing the text, change the focus to somewhere else.  When the focus is changed, the event fires and the page examines the new input, calculates remaining characters and speaks the changed text. In the code above, change the line:

```
MsgBox narrative.innerHTML
```

to read

```
btnReadText.Focus
```

This will eliminate the messagebox and replace it with focusing on the submit button before clicking it.